# Django: order by position ignoring NULL

Tags: django, sql-order-by, nullable

I have a problem with Django queryset ordering.

My model contains a field named `position`, a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` which I'd like to used to order query results.

I use `order_by('position')`, which works great.

**Problem** : my `position` field is nullable (`null=True, blank=True`), because I don't wan't to specify a position for every 50000 instances of my model. When some instances have a `NULL` `position`, `order_by` returns them in the top of the list: I'd like them to be at the end.

In raw SQL, I used to write things like:

```sql
IF(position IS NULL or position='', 1, 0)
```

(see http://www.shawnolson.net/a/730/mysql-sort-order-with-null.html). Is it possible to get the same result using Django, without writing raw SQL?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the annotate() from [django agrregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) to do the trick:

```
items = Item.objects.all().annotate(null_position=Count('position')).order_by('-null_position', 'position')
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me, maybe because I have as an ordering field:  position__name (which is position.name). Too bad.
Ah, wait! I renamed the null_position to null and it seems django does not like that! Working now, thanks! :)

Comment: Performance won't be good since it becomes an aggregate query.

Comment: Django 1.11 builds in proper support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731168/237091

Answer (score 21):

As of Django 1.8 you can use [`Coalesce()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to convert `NULL` to `0`.

Sample:

```
import datetime    
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Value

from app import models


# Coalesce works by taking the first non-null value.  So we give it
# a date far before any non-null values of last_active.  Then it will
# naturally sort behind instances of Box with a non-null last_active value.

the_past = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=10*365)
boxes = models.Box.objects.all().annotate(
    new_last_active=Coalesce(
        'last_active', Value(the_past)
    )
).order_by('-new_last_active')
```

Comment: thanks for that link -- here's how I used `Coalesce` on datetime attributes: https://gist.github.com/yosemitebandit/ec3adc02d927375f13d0

Comment: @Matt's code should be added to the answer - it makes it twice as useful

Comment: I added @Matts sample to my answer, so do don't forget to update both of us :-)

Comment: There is a problem with this in which it says unicode is missing tzinfo.

Comment: it's a shame Coalesce doesn't also work for empty strings

Comment: In newest Django versions `Value` can be found directly from `django.db.models`.

Answer (score 14):

It's a shame there are a lot of questions like this on SO that are not marked as duplicate. See (for example) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798609/1600612) for the native solution for Django 1.11 and newer. Here is a short excerpt:

> Added the nulls_first and nulls_last parameters to Expression.asc() and desc() to control the ordering of null values.

Example usage (from comment to that answer):

```
from django.db.models import F 
MyModel.objects.all().order_by(F('price').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Credit goes to the original answer author and commenter.

Answer (score 9):

Using extra() as Ignacio said optimizes a lot the end query. In my aplication I've saved more than 500ms (that's a lot for a query) in database processing using extra() instead of annotate()

Here is how it would look like in your case:

```
items = Item.objects.all().extra(
    'select': {
        'null_position': 'CASE WHEN {tablename}.position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'
     }
).order_by('-null_position', 'position')
```

{tablename} should be something like **{Item's app}_item** following django's default tables name.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the syntax in Pablo's answer needed to be updated to the following on my 1.7.1 install:

```
items = Item.objects.all().extra(select={'null_position': 'CASE WHEN {name of Item's table}.position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'}).order_by('-null_position', 'position')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`QuerySet.extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) can be used to inject expressions into the query and order by them.

Comment: It is deprecated by now.

Comment: `.extra()` is not deprecated. But it may be in the future.