# Ordering a Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model --

```
class VideoCredit(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(VideoInfo)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', blank=True, null=True)
    normalized_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to order credits by whether they have a profile, and then by noramlized_name, for example --

```
# for the following entries 

id   video             profile           normalized_name
1    Terminator        Terry Gilliam     Terry Gilliam
2    Terminator        James Cameron     James Cameron
3    Dracula            Null              Bela Lugosi

# it would order as: [James Cameron, Terry Gilliam, Bela Lugosi]
```

I tried doing `ordering=['-profile_full_name', 'normalized_name']`, but it would order profile first, but in reverse alphabetical order. If I did `profile_full_name` instead, it would return those without a profile (a NULL field), at the beginning. How would I do this? Thank you.

**Update:** I got it down to this, which is working nicely:

```
recent_activity=[]
for object in RecentActivity.objects.select_related.all()[:50]:
    if object.event_type == 2:
        credits_yes_profile = object.content_object.videocredit_set.exclude(profile=None).order_by('profile__full_name')
        credits_no_profile = object.content_object.videocredit_set.filter(profile=None).order_by('normalized_name')
        sorted_credits = list(credits_yes_profile) + list(credits_no_profile)
        recent_activity.append((object, sorted_credits))
    else:
        recent_activity.append((object, ''))
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
recent_activity=[]
for object in RecentActivity.objects.select_related.all()[:50]:
    if object.event_type == 2:
        credits_yes_profile = object.content_object.videocredit_set.exclude(profile=None).order_by('profile__full_name')
        credits_no_profile = object.content_object.videocredit_set.filter(profile=None).order_by('normalized_name')
        sorted_credits = list(credits_yes_profile) + list(credits_no_profile)
        recent_activity.append((object, sorted_credits))
    else:
        recent_activity.append((object, ''))
```