# Django Ordering Query Set in ascending order

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to order my `QuerySet` in ascending order for this case:

```
PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
(1, "P1"),
(2, "P2"),
(3, "P3"),
(4, "P4"),
(5, "P5"),
)

class Task(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     priority = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

Now, since, the priority can accept None values. The problem is with ordering the Query set when I do this in my View code:

```
task_list = Task.objects.all().order_by("priority")
```

This returns me the query set with the objects arranged in ascending order of priority, with the None values first. I want the ascending list but I want to include the None values at the end. I have a huge database so, I am interested in accomplishing this at the database level.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably your best option.

```
import itertools
q = itertools.chain(
        Task.objects.filter(priority__isnull=False).order_by("priority"),
        Task.objects.filter(priority__isnull=True))
# Then you can iterate over your custom order
result = [(x.name, x.priority) for x in q]
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks as a good option. And I guess chain function is a C level operation so, I think it shouldn't be much memory intensive.

Comment: It is some solution, but I would prefer something that actually returns a queryset where you can chain other calls (filter, etc.) so that it could be return by ``get_query_set`` for a manager. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can change order to descending using `queryset.order_by('-field')` (prepending "-" symbol), but there is no way in Django to tell how nulls should be sorted - it's database specific behavior. If using descending ordering still gives you null values first in your database -  use `queryset.extra(select={'order': 'custom_sql_function(priority)'}).order_by('order')`, where `custom_sql_function` converts field to integer if it is null, and is specific for your database engine.
For faster performance you can create db index on `function(field)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply like this in the Model like this

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    feild_1 = models.CharField( max_length=150)
    feild_2 = models.CharField( max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = [F('order').asc(nulls_last=True)]
```