# Django: Adding "NULLS LAST" to query

Tags: python, sql, django

I would like to sort a model by using Postgresql's "NULLS LAST" option.
How could it be done?

I tried something like

`MyModel.objects.all().extra(order_by=('-price', 'NULLS LAST'))`

But I get

"Cannot resolve keyword 'NULLS LAST' into field"

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F  
MyModel.objects.all().order_by(F('price').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

This functionality has been added to Django 1.11.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/

> Added the nulls_first and nulls_last parameters to Expression.asc()
> and desc() to control the ordering of null values.

Reference for Django 3.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values

Comment: Is there a way to add this to `Meta` class of a model? Or are we doing the same, using `F` objects in `ordering` field of `Meta`?

Comment: Is there any extra overhead to the resulting query ? I wanted to use this in a generic method where the ordering field will be passed. Some fields are not null fields, so this is not required for them. some fields are null too. For a not null field, could adding this make an extra overhead to the query ?

Comment: This is very useful when you want to order elements and use sorted query e.g. in 'for'. I found problem with using described order with first() / last(). They both returns first element of the query.

Comment: I was writing this wrong `MyModel.objects.filter(something=something).order_by(F('fieldname')).desc(nulls_last=True)`.  It is correctly written as `MyModel.objects.filter(something=something).order_by(F('fieldname').desc(nulls_last=True))`.  Note that the .desc() or .asc() is modifying the F().  Makes total sense if you think about it but I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 24):

Closest thing I've found is doing it on two steps. First ordering on the populated field and then on the nulls:

Via [this](https://gist.github.com/jpadilla/4210782) gist (itself via these [django logs](http://django-irc-logs.com/2012/dec/05/)):

```
all_projects = Project.objects.select_related().filter(
    company=company).order_by('-date_due')

q = all_projects.extra(select={'date_due_null': 'date_due is null'})
q = q.extra(order_by=['date_due_null'])
print q.query
```

Caution: note the [warnings regarding `extra()`, and that it may be deprecated in the future](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there's a perfect solution for this, or at least one that's directly contemplated by Django, given [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/sxbpqmkRyCU/qUYjX3niCOEJ) by Malcolm Treddinick.

Answer (score 23):

If you want it to be done transparently and on all columns, you can redefine sql generation. To do so, you would need to have your own Manager to return your custom QuerySet to return your custom Query to use custom Compiler. My code for that looks like that (Django 1.5):

```
from django.db import models, connections

class NullsLastQuery(models.sql.query.Query):
    """
    Query that uses custom compiler,
    to utilize PostgreSQL feature of setting position of NULL records
    """
    def get_compiler(self, using=None, connection=None):
        if using is None and connection is None:
            raise ValueError("Need either using or connection")
        if using:
            connection = connections[using]

        # defining that class elsewhere results in import errors
        from django.db.models.sql.compiler import SQLCompiler
        class NullsLastSQLCompiler(SQLCompiler):
            def get_ordering(self):
                result, group_by = super(NullsLastSQLCompiler, self
                    ).get_ordering()
                if self.connection.vendor == 'postgresql' and result:
                    result = [line + " NULLS LAST" for line in result]
                return result, group_by

        return NullsLastSQLCompiler(self, connection, using)

class NullsLastQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None):
        super(NullsLastQuerySet, self).__init__(model, query, using)
        self.query = query or NullsLastQuery(self.model)

class NullsLastManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return NullsLastQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class YourModel(models.Model):
    objects = NullsLastManager()
```

Comment: This is slightly evil, but brilliant.

Answer (score 13):

This was probably not available when the question was asked, but since Django 1.8 I think this is the best solution:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce, Value
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(price_null=
    Coalesce('price', Value(-100000000)).order_by('-price_null')
```

`Coalesce` selects the first non-null value, so you create a value `price_null` to order by which is just price but with `null` replaced by `-100000000` (or `+`?).

Comment: It's actually a great hack since it not requires to create NULLS LAST indexes and such kind of things to speedup querying

Comment: @valentjedi Doesn't this require an expression index with `Coalesce('price', Value(-100000000)`? That would be the same as creating a NULLS LAST index. Here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99009 someone states the same as I'm saying

Comment: @jperelli you're right actually. But in my case this hack was faster than adding NULLS LAST so it satisfied me.

Comment: This worked for me. I used it along with django 1.11's Subquery expression

Comment: Value is not available in django.db.models.functions module. It is available in django.db.models module instead.

Answer (score 11):

For Django 1.9 (and possibly 1.8) you can use this:

```
from django.db import connections, models
from django.db.models.sql.compiler import SQLCompiler


class NullsLastSQLCompiler(SQLCompiler):
    def get_order_by(self):
        result = super().get_order_by()
        if result and self.connection.vendor == 'postgresql':
            return [(expr, (sql + ' NULLS LAST', params, is_ref))
                    for (expr, (sql, params, is_ref)) in result]
        return result


class NullsLastQuery(models.sql.query.Query):
    """Use a custom compiler to inject 'NULLS LAST' (for PostgreSQL)."""

    def get_compiler(self, using=None, connection=None):
        if using is None and connection is None:
            raise ValueError("Need either using or connection")
        if using:
            connection = connections[using]
        return NullsLastSQLCompiler(self, connection, using)


class NullsLastQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None, hints=None):
        super().__init__(model, query, using, hints)
        self.query = query or NullsLastQuery(self.model)
```

And then on your model(s):

```
objects = NullsLastQuerySet.as_manager()
```

This is based on the answer from Tim in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077587/15690.

The ticket to add support for this to Django has been re-opened: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13312.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to include functionality for placing empty strings at the end as well?

Comment: @Duncan not without being payed for at the moment, sorry.. ;)

Comment: @blueyed, no problem. I was able to get it to work nicely by using annotations with a combination of Case and When expressions

Answer (score 3):

[@kabucey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query/42798609#42798609) is best for Django >= 1.11, but if you're using at least Django 1.8, 1.9 or 1.10, you can use a custom `Func` expression to achieve "NULLS Last" behaviour, as described at https://www.isotoma.com/blog/2015/11/23/sorting-querysets-with-nulls-in-django/:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class IsNull(Func):
    template = '%(expressions)s IS NULL'

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    price_isnull=IsNull('price_isnull'),
    ).order_by(
        'price_isnull',
        '-price',
        )
```

The first `order_by` argument sorts the list in ascending order by `price_isnull`, forcing null-price items to the end of the list since `True > False`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an another way to add managed nulls functionality to Django < v1.11 with Django v1.11 style:

```
from my_project.utils.django import F
MyModel.objects.all().order_by(F('price').desc(nulls_last=True))
# or
MyModel.objects.all().order_by(F('price').desc().nullslast())
```

Cons:

1. Easy migration to Django 1.11
2. We don't get deep into query compiler internals

To do so we need to override django.db.models.F and django.db.models.expressions.OrderBy classes:

```
from django.db.models import F as DjangoF
from django.db.models.expression import OrderBy as DjangoOrderBy


class OrderBy(DjangoOrderBy):
    def __init__(self, expression, descending=False, nulls_last=None):
        super(OrderBy, self).__init__(expression, descending)
        self.nulls_last = nulls_last
    ...

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, template=None, **extra_context):
        ...
        ordering_value = 'DESC' if self.descending else 'ASC'
        if self.nulls_last is not None:
            nulls_value = 'LAST' if self.nulls_last else 'FIRST'
            ordering_value += ' NULLS ' + nulls_value

        placeholders = {
            'expression': expression_sql,
            'ordering': ordering_value,
        }
        ...

    def nullslast(self):
        self.nulls_last = True

    def nullsfirst(self):
        self.nulls_last = False


class F(DjangoF):
    ...

    def asc(self, nulls_last=None):
        return OrderBy(self, nulls_last=nulls_last)

    def desc(self, nulls_last=None):
        return OrderBy(self, descending=True, nulls_last=nulls_last)
```

Answer (score 1):

We wanted to chain multiple order by statements, some ASC, some DESC all with NULLS LAST. There doesn't seem to be the possibility of this with order_by as it has the following call:

```
obj.query.clear_ordering(force_empty=False)
```

So you can do it with the following by appending add_ordering calls:

```
qs = ATeamModel.objects.filter(whatever=1)
qs.query.add_ordering(F('date_updated').desc(nulls_last=True))
qs.query.add_ordering(F('date_created').desc(nulls_last=True))

qs...
```