# Why Django ascending order_by date field returns None values at the end?

Tags: django, date, sql-order-by

Why Django order_by ascending date field returns None values at the end.

How to return query with None values first if order_by ascending and on the end if descending?

For example I have field calls 'my_date' and three values:

```
[2015.02.13, None, 2015.02.11]
```

After order_by('my_date') the result is:

```
[2015.02.11, 2015.02.13, None],
```

but I would like to have:

```
[None, 2015.02.11, 2015.02.13]
```

After order_by('-my_date') the result is:

```
[None, 2015.02.13, 2015.02.11]
```

but I would like to have:

```
[2015.02.13, 2015.02.11, None]
```

Comment: You'll need to write your own override to the order_by method to specify this I'd imagine, What is the actual problem your trying to solve? where do the None's come from in the first place?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query) shows how to do it using `extra()`. However, note that using `extra()` is now discouraged, so there should be a cleaner way to it. For Django 1.8+, it should be possible to write a `NullsLast` expression (see Ticket [#24060](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24060)), but I can't see an implementation, and I can't figure out how to write it off the top of my head.

Comment: I've got date field in table. Some dates are not specified. I've got requirement that empty dates must be first when ascending sort is setup.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair for your answer, but I have seen this post before I did mine post. This is not exactly the same. Procedure mentioned in that post cause that Nones are always at the end of the table, regardless of ascending or descending.

Comment: I linked to that question as a hint, I didn't mean that it was the exact solution. Building on that answer, you can use `-date_due_null` when you want nulls first.