# Peewee: how to do ORDER BY ... NULLS (FIRST|LAST)?

Tags: postgresql, peewee

The title pretty much sums it up: I would like to specify whether nulls appear first or last in my results. In my specific case, I want to get nulls last with a descending sort order, corresponding to SQL like this:

```
SELECT id, something, something_else
FROM mytable
ORDER BY something DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

This is the PostgreSQL syntax (which is what I'm using for this project). The same problem could apply with other databases (though I don't think MySQL supports that syntax, not sure if it even supports the feature). Of course having nulls first is default for ascending order [(see PostgreSQL docs)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY), so only the combinations DESC NULLS FIRST and ASC NULLS LAST are likely to be useful...except that, conveniently, the MySQL default is [precisely the opposite.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

It seems like I should be able to do one of these:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(MyModel.something.desc().nulls_first())
MyModel.select().order_by(MyModel.something.desc(nulls_first))
```

I'm no Python guru but I couldn't find anything in the Peewee documentation or source code that looks like it would do what I want.

Of course there may be many workarounds. Here are the ones I found or thought of, in decreasing order of practicality (for me):

- using raw SQL (which could actually work in my case, but isn't so great if I need the objects later)
- faking it by ordering by something else (such as a function, which I'm not sure how to do with Peewee either, or adding a derived column along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125261/6748105))
- maybe using UNION to combine a query having WHERE ?? IS NOT NULL with one having WHERE ?? IS NULL ... but that seems problematic on several fronts, such as I don't know if Peewee can do that either, and it might still be best to do ORDER BY on the whole thing anyway
- running two separate queries and putting their result sets together in Python ... again, sounds like trouble I think (extra overhead, need 1 transaction for data integrity)
- redesign the schema so I don't have to order by something that could be null (maybe someday...)

So: can Peewee do this? If not, is there a better workaround than I've thought of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating the issue, to be honest.

As of Peewee 3.x, you can specify the handling of nulls:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(MyModel.something.desc(nulls='LAST'))
```

You can also use a case statement to create an aliased column containing a 1 or 0 to indicate whether the column you're sorting on is null. Then use that alias in the order by.

Comment: thanks, hadn't realized I could do that. For future reference: the second option is tricky when doing a join (as I am) because you'd have to know what table alias is being used if you need to order by a common column name. The first option worked perfectly (after I realized I should not be putting the additional column references inside the same clause!).

Comment: UPDATE: With new versions of peewee, Clause() is no longer available. But in this case, there's a better way now: `.order_by(MyModel.field.desc(nulls="LAST"))`. (Works on peewee version 3.5.0; answer above was for 2.x ... not sure when it changed exactly.)