# Alternative nullif in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

Use Postgres as db and Django 1.9

I have some model with field 'price'. 'Price' blank=True.
On ListView, I get query set. Next, I want to sort by price with price=0 at end.

How I can write in SQL it:
'ORDER BY NULLIF('price', 0) NULLS LAST'

How write it on Django ORM? Or on rawsql?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. I found alternative. Write own NullIf with django func.

```
from django.db.models import Func

class NullIf(Func):
    template = 'NULLIF(%(expressions)s, 0)'
```

And use it for queryset:

```
queryset.annotate(new_price=NullIf('price')).order_by('new_price')
```

**Edit** : Django 2.2 and above have this implemented out of the box. The equivalent code will be

```
from django.db.models.functions import NullIf
from django.db.models import Value
queryset.annotate(new_price=NullIf('price', Value(0)).order_by('new_price')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still `ORDER BY PRICE NULLS LAST` if in your select you select the price as `SELECT NULLIF('price', 0)`. That way you get the ordering you want, but the data is returned in the way you want. In django ORM  you would select the price with `annotate` eg `TableName.objects.annotate(price=NullIf('price', 0)` and for the order by `NULLS LAST` and for the order by I'd follow the recommendations here [Django: Adding "NULLS LAST" to query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15121093/2578505)

Otherwise you could also `ORDER BY NULLIF('price', 0) DESC` but that will reorder the other numeric values. You can also obviously exclude null prices from the query entirely if you don't require them.

Comment: How import NullIf? From which module?

Comment: @VoidArray
`from django.db.models.functions import NullIf`