# Change Sort Grouping For Null Values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When using the sorting feature in the Django Rest Framework, you are given the ability to sort by a particular field, ascending and descending.

This sorting groups null values first and then alphanumeric values secondly. (and understandably so because None is less than "a")

But is there any way that we can reverse this order to where all of our alphanumeric values are sorted and then grouped after that are all of the null values?

Currently when sorting, this is the order of the queryset.

First Names:

- None
- None
- Abby
- Ben

But the desired behavior is as follows.

First Names:

- Abby
- Ben
- None
- None

---

Info:

I am using the OrderingFilter from by viewset.

This is the url for the api endpoint `http://192.168.1.85/people/?ordering=first_name`

And in the DRF OrderingFilter class, the filter_queryset method calls this code here `queryset.order_by(*ordering)` which leads me to think that this can be resolved from the queryset itself.

---

Note:

I'm not sure if the solution would be in DRF, Django, or simply in the Python language itself. Any would do.

Comment: Here is a good way using F-expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798609/115246

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Adding "NULLS LAST" to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query)