# Sorting querysets by annotated field of reverse relation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 2 models, Form and Row, Each Row has a FK to a Form.
I want to sort my Forms by the time of last row addition.

```
class Form(models.Model):
    ...

class Row(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(
        Form,
        related_name="rows",
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
```

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
queryset = Form.objects.filter(is_empty=False)
queryset = queryset.annotate(last_submit=Max("rows__created_at")).order_by('-last_submit')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After annotation, you need to call [**`order_by()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) method.

```
sorted_qs = Form.objects.filter(is_empty=False
                                ).annotate(last_submit=Max("rows__created_at")
                                           ).order_by('-last_submit')
```

### Update:

One possible cause not seeing the newly created `Form` instance at the beginning of the queryset is, some of the `Row` object may not have **`created_at`** value, so that becomes first. In such situations, you can change the *order by* behavior by setting ***`nulls_last=True`***. For more details, ref this SO post, [**Django: Adding “NULLS LAST” to query**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query)

Comment: I will add that now, i forget to mention it. I am using this, but it doesn't seem to be working. the order changes, but when I add a new row, it doesnt come to the front of the query.

Comment: *" I add a new row, it doesnt come to the front of the query..."* Which instance did you add? `Form` or `Row`?

Comment: well for example if I add a row with created_at=now(), I want the corresponding form to be the first form after ordering, but this does not happen.

Comment: so i found out my code was working fine, except there are some forms that have no submits, and django thinks that None is greater than any date :))

Comment: in such case, use this ordering technique, [Django: Adding “NULLS LAST” to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query)

Comment: this is nice! thank you! can you add this to your original answer as well?