# How to sort list in DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

I've got two models with onetoone relation user and blog. While listing users I want to have users with blog on top. How to order users so that users with blog is on first of list and secondary order by users id?
My Models:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Blog(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='blog', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My view:

```
class UserAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Adding "NULLS LAST" to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an `Exists` subquery with:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class UserAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.order_by(
        Exists(Blog.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('pk'))).desc()
    )
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

We thus determine for each `User` if there is a `Blog` for that `User`, and we sort `true` before `false` by making use of the [**`.desc(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc).