# sort products by rating high-low low-high

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Am trying to setup so my products on the products site can be sorted by the rating high-low and low-high and show the none rated behind them. I cant seem to figure it out so any help would be appreciated. I added the code ithink is needed if you need anything more i will add it.
Thanks in advance.

[image: current look high-low]

I want when sorting by high to low it has the review with the highest rating first and if it dosent have any rating it goes to the far back behind the ones with any rating.

[image: current look low-high]

I want it to have the lowest rated ones first then the none rated ones at the last after the rated ones.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

from .models import Product, Category, Review
from .forms import ProductForm, ReviewForm

# Create your views here.

    def all_products(request):
        """ A view to show all products, including sorting and search queries """
    
        products = Product.objects.all()
        query = None
        categories = None
        sort = None
        direction = None
    
        if request.GET:
            if 'sort' in request.GET:
                sortkey = request.GET['sort']
                sort = sortkey
                if sortkey == 'name':
                    sortkey = 'lower_name'
                    products = products.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
                if sortkey == 'category':
                    sortkey = 'category__name'
                if 'direction' in request.GET:
                    direction = request.GET['direction']
                    if direction == 'desc':
                        sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
                products = products.order_by(sortkey)
                
            if 'category' in request.GET:
                categories = request.GET['category'].split(',')
                products = products.filter(category__name__in=categories)
                categories = Category.objects.filter(name__in=categories)
    
            if 'q' in request.GET:
                query = request.GET['q']
                if not query:
                    messages.error(request, "You didn't enter any search criteria!")
                    return redirect(reverse('products'))
                
                queries = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
                products = products.filter(queries)
    
        current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'
    
        context = {
            'products': products,
            'search_term': query,
            'current_categories': categories,
            'current_sorting': current_sorting,
        }
    
        return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
    
    
    def product_detail(request, product_id):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            rating = request.POST.get('rating', 3)
            content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            Review.objects.create(
                product=product,
                rating=rating,
                content=content,
                created_by=request.user
            )
            # redirect to the same page
            return redirect('product_detail', product_id=product_id)
    
        reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('-id')
        context = {
            'product': product,
            'reviews': reviews
        }
        return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_friendly_name(self):
        return self.friendly_name


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_rating(self):
        reviews_total = 0

        for review in self.reviews.all():
            reviews_total += review.rating

        if reviews_total > 0:
            return reviews_total / self.reviews.count()

        return 0


class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    RATINGS = ((1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'))
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=RATINGS[2], choices=RATINGS)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.product.name, self.created_by)
```

**products.html template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_header %}
    <div class="container header-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center mt-3">
                <h2 class="logo-font">Products</h2>
                {% for c in current_categories %}
                    <a class="category-badge text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ c.name }}">
                        <span class="p-2 mt-2 badge badge-white text-black rounded-0 border border-dark">{{ c.friendly_name }}</span>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr class="w-50 mb-1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product-container col-10 offset-1">
                <div class="row mt-1 mb-2">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto order-md-last d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
                        <div class="sort-select-wrapper w-50">
                            <select id="sort-selector" class="custom-select custom-select-sm rounded-0 border border-{% if current_sorting != 'None_None' %}info{% else %}black{% endif %}">
                                <option value="reset" {% if current_sorting == 'None_None' %}selected{% endif %}>Sort by...</option>
                                <option value="price_asc" {% if current_sorting == 'price_asc' %}selected{% endif %}>Price (low to high)</option>
                                <option value="price_desc" {% if current_sorting == 'price_desc' %}selected{% endif %}>Price (high to low)</option>
                                <option value="rating_asc" {% if current_sorting == 'rating_asc' %}selected{% endif %}>Rating (low to high)</option>
                                <option value="rating_desc" {% if current_sorting == 'rating_desc' %}selected{% endif %}>Rating (high to low)</option>
                                <option value="name_asc" {% if current_sorting == 'name_asc' %}selected{% endif %}>Name (A-Z)</option>
                                <option value="name_desc" {% if current_sorting == 'name_desc' %}selected{% endif %}>Name (Z-A)</option>
                                <option value="category_asc" {% if current_sorting == 'category_asc' %}selected{% endif %}>Category (A-Z)</option>
                                <option value="category_desc" {% if current_sorting == 'category_desc' %}selected{% endif %}>Category (Z-A)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-first">
                        <p class="text-muted mt-3 text-center text-md-left">
                            {% if search_term or current_categories or current_sorting != 'None_None' %}
                                <span class="small"><a href="{% url 'products' %}">Products Home</a> | </span>
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ products|length }} Products{% if search_term %} found for <strong>"{{ search_term }}"</strong>{% endif %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    {% for product in products %}
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                            <div class="card h-100 border-0">
                                {% if product.image %}
                                <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                                </a>
                                {% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                                </a>
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                    <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer bg-white pt-0 border-0 text-left">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">${{ product.price }}</p>
                                            {% if product.category %}
                                            <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                                                <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                                                </a>
                                            </p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if product.get_rating > 0 %}
                                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1" style=color:blue;></i>{{ product.get_rating|floatformat:1 }} / 5</small>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <small class="text-muted">No Rating</small>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                                                <small class="ml-3">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'edit_product' product.id %}">Edit</a> |
                                                    <a class="text-danger" href="{% url 'delete_product' product.id %}">Delete</a>
                                                </small>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:1 %}
                            <div class="col-12 d-sm-none mb-5">
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                            <div class="col-12 d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none mb-5">
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                            <div class="col-12 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none mb-5">
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                            <div class="col-12 d-none d-xl-block mb-5">
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btt-button shadow-sm rounded-0 border border-black">
        <a class="btt-link d-flex h-100">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-black mx-auto my-auto"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% include 'newsletter/newsletter.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block postloadjs %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.btt-link').click(function(e) {
            window.scrollTo(0,0)
        })
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#sort-selector').change(function() {
            var selector = $(this);
            var currentUrl = new URL(window.location);

            var selectedVal = selector.val();
            if(selectedVal != "reset"){
                var sort = selectedVal.split("_")[0];
                var direction = selectedVal.split("_")[1];

                currentUrl.searchParams.set("sort", sort);
                currentUrl.searchParams.set("direction", direction);

                window.location.replace(currentUrl);
            } else {
                currentUrl.searchParams.delete("sort");
                currentUrl.searchParams.delete("direction");

                window.location.replace(currentUrl);
            }
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you provide the current output and the desired output?

Comment: Yes i added some pictures how its looking now and a discription on how i want it.

Comment: Maybe this could help to get the unrated results last https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798609/10992051

Comment: try combine sorting like `.order_by("price", "-rating")` # will sort by min price and highest rating (price asc and rating desc)