# Nested serializer ordering when there is no object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using drf to create API view like this:

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "attribute1": "some attribute",
    "attribute2": "some attribute",
    "attribute3": "some attribute",
    "attribute4": "some attribute",
    "stats": {
         "status": false,
         "count": 0
     }
}
```

`stats` field is created as serializer (OneToOneField in models), but sometimes there is no object associated in this OneToOne relation so `stats` is `null`.

Problem is I want to order my queryset by f.e. `stats__count`. Ascending order of this sorting is working. `count = 0` is at the beggining and nulls are at the end, but when I want to sort it in descending order I want to have biggest value of this attribute at the beggining. I'm getting all the nulls instead.

Question is: how to place this elements with `stats = null` at the end of result or at least remove them from queryset (but only when ordering by field from `stats`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to use annotate() as described in this SO question: [Django : Order by position ignoring NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null)

```
items = Item.objects.all().annotate(null_position=Count('position')).order_by('-null_position', 'position')
```

Comment: I can't remove it from queryset because they also need to be displayed. What I want is that they should be ommited while ordering,

Comment: Ah okay, then check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null

Comment: Looks like using annotate will do just what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks that worked, you can edit the answer so I can accept it :)